# Django URL not rendering templates

Tags: django, django-urls

Instead of directing me to the page django is simply returning the following error:

> “C:\Users\RodrigoPinto\Desktop\Insider\users\register” does not exist

This is my url;

```
from django.urls import path
from users import employee_views
from users import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html')),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('register/', auth_views.Register.as_view, name='register'),
    path('profile/', auth_views.Profile.as_view, name='profile'),
    path('listView/', employee_views.AccountsListView.as_view, name='listView'),
    path('update/<pk>/', employee_views.AccountsUpdate.as_view, name='updateView'),
    path('password_update/<pk>/', employee_views.update_password, name='password_update'),
    path('delete/<pk>/', employee_views.AccountsDelete.as_view, name='deleteView'),
]
```

and on the main app i have this inside the URL;

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from users import urls as user_urls

app_name = "inside"

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('inside.urls')),
    path('users/', include(user_urls)),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I've been over this code for the last two hours and I cant understand what I'm doing wrong. Maybe someone can see something that I'm missing.

Also my template directory in settings is configured like this;

```
template_dir = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'users', 'templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'forums', 'templates'),
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': template_dir,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

views.py;

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import UserCreateForm
from django.views.generic import CreateView, TemplateView
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class Register(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')
    template_name = 'users/register.html'
    success_message = 'Your Account has been created!'


class Profile(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
```

separate file to keep code cleaner employee_views.py;

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.messages import error, success
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import User


@login_required()
def update_password(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form_data = request.POST
        if form_data['password1'] == form_data['password2'] and len(form_data['password1']) > 7:
            u = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
            u.set_password(form_data['password1'])
            success(request, "Your Password has been updated!")
            u.save()
            return redirect(reverse('users:listView'))
        else:
            error(request, "Please check your passwords!")
            return render(request, "users/users/change_password.html", context={'pk': pk})

    return render(request, "users/users/change_password.html", context={'pk': pk})


class Profile(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'


class AccountsListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = User
    paginate_by = 15
    template_name = "users/profile.html"


class AccountsUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ('username',
              'first_name',
              'last_name',
              'email',
              'image',
              'is_admin',
              'is_supervisor',
              )
    template_name = 'user_update_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:listView')


class AccountsDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = User
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:listView')
    template_name = 'users/user_confirm_delete.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is 99% sure in this statement:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I guess in your settings.py you have something like

```
MEDIA_URL = '/users/register/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/....../register'
```

You access "127.0.0.1:8000/users/register/ and the static(...) catches the request and produces exactly the error message you get.

That is also the reason why you do not get the usual detailed Django Error trace.

Answer (score 1):

If your using generic class based views you need to have the structure like this

```
app_name
|
|--templates
    | 
    | -- app_name
            |
            |--register.html
```

If the error is occuring the login url, its looking in the specifed template for register.html.

Comment: Insider is simply the project name and inside is the app that's just rendering the index page and will have some other stuff in the future.

Comment: Please see my edit. If the project name is Insider you dont need to refernece that in the URL, unless you have specifically hardcoded that path somewhere

Comment: Oh i get what your confusion is, im not using the file path as url in the browser, im using 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/inside/users/login' that local file path is the django error.

Comment: I sent it too soon. I fixed my answer. Can you also display the complete traceback in your question? Also the templates and views might help too.

Comment: There's no traceback. It's just that error, for some reason i cant understand django is not looking to render a template, will update question to include my views in just a second.

Comment: The url for the index that is working fine is:http://localhost:8000 and when i try to acess the registration form i go by http://localhost:8000/users/register and it gives me that message, its not even an error;C:\Users\RodrigoPinto\Desktop\Insider\users\register” does not exist

Comment: If you can display the entire traceback. Then we can help. If its a TemplateDoesNotExists error, its the name of your template in your views. That would be the importance of showing your views, templates, and entire traceback

Comment: No, theres no call back its just  that message. That's why im confused. https://gyazo.com/67d1fb3c07944aa3321849550e46a182

Comment: I updated my answer. It’s a 404 but different. I wonder if it’s the way you have template dirs configured too. I would try returning that to an empty list and try the configuration in my edited answer

Comment: That is exactly how i have it. Django is very picky how you have the templates. My friend who's way more experienced than i am was also looking thru the project on git and we cant figure out why it doesn't work.